# Java chat app video streaming

Tags: java, videoview, streaming, app, online-video

Всем привет! У меня есть мини Джава чат с клиентом и сервером. Дело в том что я хочу добавить туда видео стриминг(вебинар) и аудио а сам понятия не имею как это сделать? Может какие-то идеи ? Или есть open source библиотеки ?